# 'Said' infront of the sentence

Tags: symbols

Juan Dela Cruz is a former member of this District formerly assigned at ABCD. Said employee was transferred to ZXC.

Does capital Said infront of the sentence correct? it seems to me it' wrong

Comment: so it is grammatically correct sir?

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct, although not used very often. You could translate it loosely as

> "The employee that was mentioned just now."

It's a fairly formal usage, probably more common in legal language, news or government reports, and less common in everyday conversation.